# How to read this XML file in Java?

Tags: java, xml

My XML is like

```
<Student>
<ST ID="01">
    <Name>Huan</Name>
    <Subject>
        <SJ CLASS="001">
            <SJName>Toan</SJName>
            <Point>8.0</Point>
        </SJ>
    </Subject>
</ST>
<ST ID="02">
    <Name>Le Nguyen Dai Duong</Name>
    <Subject>
        <SJ CLASS="001">
            <SJName>Toan</SJName>
            <Point>7.0</Point>
        </SJ>
    </Subject>
</ST>
```

I tried to read all the text in all tag, but the text in the tag "Subject" were repeated.

[image: result]

Comment: Perhaps you meant to write `Subject` instead of `MonHoc` in your question (there's no `MonHoc` tag in the XML)? Can you give the Java code that you used? What kind of problems did you exactly have? Please see [mcve] on how to ask properly.

Comment: Oh. I mean 'Subject'.

Comment: My code is too long. Can you show me how to read it by your way?